# SQL DateSerial returns 'overflow'

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make this query work, but it returns 'Overflow'.

```
SELECT tblReadings.DateRead
FROM tblReadings
WHERE (((tblReadings.DateRead) Between DateSerial(Date(),Date(),1) And DateSerial(Date(),Date()-10,1)));
```

The following also return 'Overflow'.

```
SELECT tblReadings.DateRead
FROM tblReadings
WHERE (((tblReadings.DateRead)=DateSerial(Date(),Date(),1)));

SELECT tblReadings.DateRead
FROM tblReadings
WHERE (((tblReadings.DateRead)=DateSerial(2016,Date(),1)));
```

Only the following gives the correct result (1 Dec 2016):

```
SELECT tblReadings.DateRead
FROM tblReadings
WHERE (((tblReadings.DateRead)=DateSerial(2016,12,1)));
```

I decompiled the database and got exactly the same results.

Comment: Read what you're writing. What would you expect `DateSerial(Date(), Date(), 1)` to produce? What it's actually producing is something like `DateSerial(47865, 47865, 1)`, which clearly isn't a valid serial date (what month is 47865 in the year 47865?). You're looking to extract the year and month from those dates, not the entire date.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. Used Year(Date(), Month(Date(), 1 etc.